# How to read CSV two columns of data at random？

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a program that can randomly allocate seats. The name and the seat are in two columns of the CSV file, I want to randomly select them and print them. I will only read one column at random. How do I write two columns of data at random?

```
#read name column at random

with open('/home/name.csv', 'r') as fp:
     for l in fp:
      foo = list(fp)
      name = random.choice(foo)
      print(name)

#This is data in csv
column0  column1
Jacob      2A
Tony       3B
Emma       1C
Jack       5D
Ada        4A
```

Now i want to random choice Name and Place at same time and print it, but i don't know how to write it.

Comment: You should use the `csv` module to read your csv file, and then use `random.choice` on the lists @LingjieJi, Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by opening your csv file by using the csv module using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), read the rows and create your names and seats list, then randomly choose from both of them via [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
import csv
import random

names = []
seats = []
#Open csv file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    #Read csv file
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
    #Skip header
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through rows and create names and seats array
    for row in reader:
        names.append(row[0])
        seats.append(row[1])

#Choose randomly from both of them
name = random.choice(names)
seat = random.choice(seats)

print(name, seat)
```

The output will look like

```
Tony 5D
Emma 1C
...
```

If you don't want to have two lists, you can instead read all rows via list-comprehension, and use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip names and seats together.

Then the first tuple contains all names, and second tuple contains all seats, and you can randomly choose from them

```
import csv
import random

rows = []
#Open csv file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    #Read csv file
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
    #Skip header
    next(reader)
    #Iterate through rows, and zip names and seats together
    rows = list(zip(*[row for row in reader]))
    #[('Jacob', 'Tony', 'Emma', 'Jack', 'Ada'), ('2A', '3B', '1C', '5D', '4A')]

name = random.choice(rows[0])
seat = random.choice(rows[1])

print(name, seat)
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer if it helped you @LingjieJi

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer @LingjieJi :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This is my `name.csv`:

```
Jacob, 2A
Tony, 3B
Emma, 1C
Jack, 5D
Ada, 4A
```

First we need to import that data into a python data structure. The simplest would be a list of lists. You can also use pandas if you know that, but I'm using lists just to show you how to get started.

```
import csv
with open('name.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]
```

Now my `data` variable is:

```
[['Jacob', ' 2A'],
 ['Tony', ' 3B'],
 ['Emma', ' 1C'],
 ['Jack', ' 5D'],
 ['Ada', ' 4A']]
```

Next, to choose a random row, I'll use `random` module of python to get a random row from the list of rows:

```
import random
random.choice(data) # Example output: ['Ada', ' 4A']
```

This will give me one of the rows from the table. You can select either of the 2 columns now.

```
name = random.choice(data)[0] # First column
seat = random.choice(data)[1] # Second column
```

Comment: Anytime mate ✌️